# Visual studio & ASP.Net : Sharing violation in post-build event

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a principal ASP.Net MVC project and other plugin projects in my solution.
When a plugin project is built, their files (dlls, views...) are copied in the principal asp.net project whith a post-build event.

> xcopy "$(TargetDir)WebPortal.Plugin.MyPlugin.dll" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\" /Y 
>   xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)Views" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\Views\"

My issue is for the copy of the plugin's DLLs. I have a "Sharing violation" error when I build for the second time.

The only solution I found is to manually stop the IIS server when I build my plugins in order to free the DLLs from the IIS process.

I need a tip to do it automatically because it is very tedious !

Comment: First, why are you using plugins? Is it for a multi-tenant solution where the actual implementation is different? Something else? The reason I ask this is I have seen a plugin style architecture used in a single implementation to "simplify", which it does anything but.

Comment: Yes, it is for a multi-tenant solution. I use MEF and additionnals controllers.

Comment: Is this to have different implementations of a specific function? Or something else?

Comment: It is to add specifics functions to generics pages and add whole specifics pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically stop and start World Wide Web service in your post build event like this:

```
net stop w3svc

xcopy "$(TargetDir)WebPortal.Plugin.MyPlugin.dll" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\" /Y 
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)Views" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\Views\"

net start w3svc
```

If you still face sharing violation error then you can put a sleep in above script for few seconds after stopping IIS service. You'll require PowerShell on your computer for this to work:

```
net stop w3svc

powershell -command "Start-Sleep -s 5"

xcopy "$(TargetDir)WebPortal.Plugin.MyPlugin.dll" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\" /Y 
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)Views" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\Views\"
    
net start w3svc
```

If you don't have powershell on your PC then try `ping` command which is bit hacky for introducing sleep but will work:

```
net stop w3svc

ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul

xcopy "$(TargetDir)WebPortal.Plugin.MyPlugin.dll" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\" /Y 
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)Views" "$(SolutionDir)WebPortal\Plugins\MyPlugin\Views\"
    
net start w3svc
```

I hope one of the above solutions will work for you.